# Google Cloud Endpoints gwt Oauth2 authentication

Tags: gwt, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints

We use Google Cloud Endpoints with a GWT application. For authentication on OAuth2, we use gwt-oauth2 (http://code.google.com/p/gwt-oauth2/) but it keeps prompting user with a popup window on the first access and every time the token expires. It is not a good user experience as it was before using just Cookie Authentication with Google Accounts. 
Does anyone knows any other way to authenticate to Endpoints with gwt without prompt the user with authorization screen, or, at least, without prompt every time the token expires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure if gwt-oauth2 supports immediate mode, but if it does, that's the solution for repeated access prompting with a popup. (If it doesn't, it's a bug/feature request for the library.)

The Google API JS client uses immediate mode to get a fresh token, without a popup window, whenever the user has previous authorized the application (as seen in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js#adding-oath-authentication)). You need to replicate this behavior inside of your library.

You will always get a popup window the first time a user accesses your application, by design.

Comment: gwt-oauth2 does not support immediate mode at this time, which is why the popup is always shown. The GWT API client libraries in the gwt-google-apis project wrap the JS client which *does* support immediate mode, you can see how it's done in https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/source/browse/trunk/apis/src/com/google/api/gwt/client

Comment: @JasonHall could adding immediate mode be as simple as adding a parameter to a call somewhere and if so, are there any ref docs on the REST interface ? I would try my luck on adding this feature then ...